# Reference to struct is Nothing

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm learning about Structure in VB.net but I actually have a trouble with this. I saw that a structure can't be Nothing compare to a Class, but I actually have a null reference error in a structure that use another structure :

```
Public Structure coord
    Public a() As Point3D
    Public b() As Point3D
End Structure

Public Structure Point3D
    Public x As Double
    Public y As Double
    Public z As Double
End Structure

Sub main()
Dim myCoord As coord
coord.a(0).x = 2.1
End Sub
```

> NullReferenceException

Any idea and explication about it ?

Comment: a and b are not structure, they are array which need to be initialized.

Comment: In vb.net you don't have to initialise an array no ? like `Dim myArray() As Integer` is enough no ?

Comment: No it isn't. An array is a reference type and therefore needs to be initialized like any other class. I.e. `Dim myArray() As Integer = New Integer(9) {} '10 items` - or: `Dim myArray(9) As Integer`.

Comment: I see a data integrity problem I the above structure. How do you know (or manage) how many `a` and `b` in each instance of `coord`? Would it be more efficient to define `coord` as just `a` and `b` - and then declare `Dim myCoord() as Coord`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the_lotus said, they are array, you need first to initialize:

```
ReDim myCoord.a(3) ' 3 for example
```

and only then you can assign values:

```
myCoord.a(0).x = 2.1

Sub main()
   Dim myCoord As coord
   ReDim myCoord.a(3) ' 3 for example
   myCoord.a(0).x = 2.1
End Sub
```

Comment: I would like to use a dynamic size array, because I don't know the size of this array before fill it. Then, should I redim this array each time I add a value inside ?

Comment: yes, or you can use ArrayList, you can find here more details here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068490/2734276

Comment: Ok I thought that dynamic array size was native in vb.net. I will use the redim solution each time I add a new value then. Thanks

Comment: @Toto NaBendo, then IMHO use a `List(Of Point3D)` many benefits... Then no need to do all that stuff... Ex: `Public a As New List(Of Point3D)`.

Comment: Trying to use a List , I can't because "non-shared members in a structure cannot be declared 'new' "

Comment: Don't want to use something that I don't understand, what will be affected by this ?

Comment: @lda573 ArrayLists became redundant in the year 2005 when the [List<T> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) was added to the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2):

Based on **[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/structures-and-classes)** coord should be a class and maybe Point3D also.

Here is an example

```
Public Class coord
    Public a As New List(Of Point3D)
    Public b As New List(Of Point3D)
End Class

Public Class Point3D
    Public x As Double = 0.0R
    Public y As Double = 0.0R
    Public z As Double = 0.0R
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim myCoord As New coord
    myCoord.a.Add(New Point3D) 'add instance to list
    myCoord.a(0).x = 2.1R
End Sub
```

Comment: Notwithstanding efficiency arguments, I think Point3D makes more sense as a value type rather than a reference type.